# Can you directly pass a non-implicit val as argument to a function expecting an implicit?

Tags: scala, implicit

Excuse the mind blank.

```
class Bar(implicit foo: Foo)

class Foo {
  implicit val self = this 
  lazy val bar = new Bar
}
```

Can we simplify the instantiation of `Bar` to a single statement where `this` is provided very ***explicitly*** as the constructor argument?

My question also applies to passing any val, not only a `this` as in this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implicit parameter in your constructor is part of the second set of parameters here (the first set is empty), so you can do

```
val bar = new Bar()(new Foo)
```

Comment: ah, so it is trivial, only needed to recall that an empty parameter list is built by the compiler right before the implicit one given. Many thanks.